# Mobx State Tree - Computed Property depending on Child Array Properties

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I have the following case

```
export const AssetList = types
  .model({
    assets: types.array(Asset),
  })
  .views((self) => ({
    get current() {
      console.log('current updated')
      return self.assets.find((el) => el.liked === null)
    },
  }))
```

Then the Asset model looks like

```
export const Asset = types
  .model({
    liked: types.maybeNull(types.boolean),
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    like() {
      console.log('like')
      self.liked = true
    },
    dislike() {
      console.log('dislike')
      self.liked = false
    },
  }))
```

The problem comes when like() is fired, it updates the `liked` property of the Asset but then the AssetList computed property `current` does not update. Not sure why this is happening or if I need to add something extra in order to make it work.

Comment: [Your code seems to be working nicely](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-tu-pvh8p?file=/src/App.tsx). Are you sure you are observing `current` in any way? MobX computeds are only cached and recalculated when they are observed.

Comment: Thank you. It worked by adding @observer to the parent component (where the model was instantiated from)